# Как заставить UI javafx обновится?

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Подскажите пожалуйста, как заставить UI обновится?

Мне нужно, чтобы перед началом обработки устанавливался текст:

```
info.setText("Calculating");
```

А второй поток должен ждать окончания выполнения первого, потому что он будет делать свои дела на основе вычислений первого, но из-за строки

```
Runnable updater = () -> info.setText("qwer");
```

Не хочет устанавливаться текст "Calculating".

То есть мне нужно сначала оповестить пользователя что идут какие-то вычисления, а потом сказать что начался второй этап вычислений.

```
info.setText("Calculating");
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    Runnable updater = () -> {
        int total = calculate(fileZ, fileT);
        info.setText("0 from " + total);
    };

    Platform.runLater(updater);
});
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();

Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
    Runnable updater = () -> info.setText("qwer");
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Platform.runLater(updater);
});
thread2.setDaemon(true);
thread2.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы оборачиваете в `Platform.runLater` выполнится не в текущем потоке, а в потоке javafx через какое-то время. По сути поток `thread` поручает потоку javafx выполнить какой-то действие (запустить `calculate`, изменить текст метки), а сам сразу завершается, не дожидаясь окончания выполнения метод `calculate`, и поток `thread2` сразу продолжает свое выполнение.

Чтобы в первом потоке дождаться завершения выполнения метода `calculate`, этот метод не должен быть обернут в runLater:

```
info.setText("Calculating");
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    int total = calculate(fileZ, fileT);
    Platform.runLater(() -> info.setText("0 from " + total));
});
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();

Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Platform.runLater(() -> info.setText("qwer"));
});
thread2.setDaemon(true);
thread2.start();
```

Если у вас внутри `calculate` есть, например, вывод в метку текущего прогресса, то *этот вывод* нужно обернуть в `runLater` (не весь метод `calculate`, не цикл, в котором есть вывод, а *только вывод*).

Также, для выполнения нескольких действий по цепочке в отдельном потоке удобно использовать `CompletableFuture`:

```
info.setText("Calculating");
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        int total = calculate(fileZ, fileT);
        Platform.runLater(() -> info.setText("0 from " + total));
    }).thenRun(() -> {
        Platform.runLater(() -> info.setText("qwer"));
    }).exceptionally(throwable -> {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    });
```

Comment: Что-то мне с трудом даётся эта тема. Спасибо за Ваш ответ.